# UDF with predefined arguments shown in Excel formula bar?

Tags: vba, excel

I am curious if anyone knows of a way to push predefined parameters to the function box in Excel when using a UDF?  This explains how to accomplish what I want, but only within the VBA editor: [VBA Function argument list select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340002/vba-function-argument-list-select)

My UDF has two arguments:

1. a single cell range
2. required parameter, either "up" or "down"

I was able to get tooltips (https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense) and add UDF/argument descriptors to the function box (Application.MacroOptions), but in an ideal world, I could push the options for the second argument to the GUI also... much like the "true/false" dropdown appears for the fourth argument of VLOOKUP:

[image]

*(ignore the tooltip overlay in the picture, I am referring to the TRUE/FALSE enumeration below it)*

**Anyone, know if this can/how this might be accomplished?**

Comment: It is not possible to display a tooltip for a user defined function.

Comment: I'm not asking about a tooltip, instead how to effectively expose an enum to the excel function box GUI.  However, that being said... it is actually possible to display a tool-tip for a UDF, I even posted a link in my question to a resource which I had no problem implementing (https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense).

Comment: Have you tried defining a`Public Enum` in the same module as your UDF and then setting your second parameter to be that enum type?

Comment: errr... not quite.  the Public Enum works for the UDF (as in the user can type 0 or 1 as described in my enum) but it doesnt bring that up to the GUI.  This answer kind of gets there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188017/how-can-i-use-enum-identifiers-in-excel-udf), but the user has to know to type "v_" to bring up the defined names.